# How to add more custom fields in user meta table simultaneously

Tags: wpdb

I am working on a task in which i have to submit some records to user_meta table at form submitting. 
Actually it is related to employee data and i just want to add records in user meta table.
I am doing with this code.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if($_POST['user_login'])
    {
                $user['user_login']=$_POST['user_login'];
                $user['user_pass']=md5($_POST['user_login']);
                $user['user_pass']=md5($_POST['user_login']);
    }
    if($_POST['email']){    $user['user_email']=$wpdb->escape($_POST['email']); }
    if($_POST['url']){  $user['user_url'] = $_POST['url'];  }
    if ($mes == '')
    {
        $flag = 1;
        if ($flag == 1 && $message == '')
        {
            if ($wpdb->insert("wp_users", $user))
            {
                    if($_POST['status'] == 'inactive')
                    {
                                $member_type = 'pending';
                                $capabilities = 'a:1:{s:7:"'.$member_type.'";b:1;}';
                                $meta_user['capabilities'] = $capabilities; 

                    }
                    elseif($_POST['status'] == 'active')
                    {
                            $member_type = 'employee';
                            $capabilities = 'a:1:{s:8:"'.$member_type.'";b:1;}';
                            $meta_user['capabilities'] = $capabilities; 
                    }

                $customer['company_id']=$company_id;
                $customer['user_id']=mysql_insert_id();
                $customer['owner']='N';

                $metauser1['user_id'] = mysql_insert_id();
                $metauser1['meta_key'] = 'member_type';
                $metauser1['meta_value'] = 'employee';

                $metauser2['user_id'] = mysql_insert_id();
                $metauser2['meta_key'] = 'nickname';
                $metauser2['meta_value'] = $user['user_login'];

                $metauser3['user_id'] = mysql_insert_id();
                $metauser3['meta_key'] = 'capabilities';
                $metauser3['meta_value'] = $meta_user['capabilities'];

                if( $wpdb->insert("wp_company_user", $customer)   && $wpdb->insert("wp_usermeta", $metauser1) && $wpdb->insert("wp_usermeta", $metauser2)&& $wpdb->insert("wp_usermeta", $metauser3))
                {
                    $_SESSION['mes']="Record has been inserted successfully.";

                exit;
                }
            }   
            else
            {
                $message="Record could not be inserted.";
            }
        }   

    }
    else
    {
        $message = $mes;
    }
}
```

I know this is not an efficient way to do this, there should be another way to insert custom meta key and meta values in user meta table.

How can i make my code efficient please tell me.
Please let me know if any code is broken.

Comment: you want to insert these `meta values` at user registration i.e wordpress registration form or is their any another form from which you want the enter these values ?

Comment: @ksr89 No actually i am just making a company programme in which a person will add employees under himself so i just want to fill some entries in user meta table.
make me sure if any confusion is there. I wanna find a smart way to solve this problem.

Comment: "Please let me know if any code is broken."-- I don't know about broken, technically, but you are using unsanitized `$_POST` data, which is dangerous.

Comment: @s_ha_dum sir where should i change my code i want to submit my records in user meta table manually and also i want them editable by edit form in user panel.
Is it possible with multiple records in a single form for user meta table.